# How to prevent autogeneration of JAXBElement for xs:choice using xsdtojava?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, jackson

I'm generating java classes from `XSD` using `cxf-xjc-plugin` and `xsdtojava` plugin.

Problem: I have no control of the `xsd`, and one element has a `xs:choice` which results in a `JAXBElement`. Unfortunately my xml serializer `jackson` cannot handle `JAXBElement`s. So I'm trying to achieve autogeneration to an `Object` rather than `JAXBElement`. But how?

The xsd I have no control of:

```
<xs:element name="payment">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="2">
            <xs:element name="creditcard">
                ...
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="debitcard">
                ...
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="iban">
                ...
            </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

xsdtojava generates:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class AutogeneratedReq {
    @XmlElementRefs({
         @XmlElementRef(name = "creditcard", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
         @XmlElementRef(name = "debitcard", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
         @XmlElementRef(name = "iban", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    })
    private List<JAXBElement<?>> payment;
}
```

But my goal is the following:

```
    @XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(name="creditcard", type=Creditcad.class, required = false),
        @XmlElement(name="debitcard", type=Debitcard.class, required = false),
        @XmlElement(name="iban", type=Iban.class, required = false)
    })
    protected List<Object> payment;
```

Or as well it would be ok generating each of the choices as single elements:

```
private List<Ceditcard> creditcard;
private List<Debitcard> debitcard;
private List<Iban> iban;
```

I tried achieving this by using a binding file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
          version="2.1"> 
    <globalBindings choiceContentProperty="true"/> 
</bindings>
```

But that did not help. What could I try more?

Comment: Single fields don't fit the XSD, because the XSD specifies that e.g. two `<creditcard>` elements are allowed.

Comment: That's correct, I changed the fields to `List<>` elements. Anyways the sole question remains how to prevent generating `JAXBElement` to *whatever*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to use the `simplify` jaxb plugin and generating the choice elements with `<simplify:as-element-property/>`.

maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

xsdtojava maven config with `cxf-xjc-plugin` must use:

```
<xsdOption>
   <bindingFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/choice-binding.xml</bindingFile>
   <extensionArgs>
     <extensionArg>-Xsimplify</extensionArg>
   </extensionArgs>
</xsdOption>
```

choice-binding.xml:

```
axb:bindings    
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:simplify="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/simplify"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc simplify"
    jaxb:version="2.1">
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="xsd/booking/bookingRequest.xsd">
                <jaxb:bindings multiple="true" node="//xs:element[@name='payment']//xs:complexType//xs:choice//xs:element">
                        <simplify:as-element-property/>
                </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:binding>
</jaxb:bindings>
```