# Java Class Generation using JAXB with XSD with nillable="true"

Tags: java, xml, ant, xsd, jaxb

I have a stuck with java class generation issue with following xsd.
```

```
<xs:element name="WsResponse" nillable="true">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="CustomerName" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element ref="AccountNumber" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element ref="MSISDN" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element ref="TotalAmount" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element ref="TaxAmount" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I'm using ant to generate java classes using `com.sun.tools.xjc.XJC2Task` and I'm having jaxb 2.2.4.

Issue I'm having is that generated `WsResponse` java class do not have the 
`@XmlRootElement` annotation.

When I remove the `nillable="true"` from the above xsd and try class generation, generated java class includes the `@XmlRootElement` annotation.

Since XSD is provided by 3rd party service I can't change that. So is there a way to have generated class to include `@XmlRootElement` annotation?

Comment: Have you tried using external global binding by `<xjc:simple/>` ?

Comment: No, `<xjc:simple/>` doesn't work.

Comment: Try using this anser [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26545603/3364187)

Comment: I tried that as well. It adds the `@XmlRootElement` to the class. But still the `ObjectFactory`  is created with `JAXBElement<WsResponse> createWsResponse(WsResponse value)`. So I get `JAXBElement` instead of `WsResponse`. Is there a way change that as well?

Comment: `JAXBElemetn<WsResponse>` is mandatory .. see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31478362/3364187). In your scenario is `minOccurs=0`, because its default value.

Comment: So that means there is nothing wrong in the class generation? When extracting the unmarshled response is it normal practice to use `JAXBIntrospector.getValue`? With that we can get the  `WsResponse` object.

Comment: Yes, the generation is correct. `JAXBElement` is used in these scenarios. You could use either `JAXBIntrospector.getValue(..)` or `getValue()` within `JAXBElement` to retrieve `WsResponse`.

Comment: Anyway if you think that the links which i reported above they were useful, I'll appreciate some up votes.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Sure I will :)