# wsdl2java generate List<JAXBElement<?>> instead of properties

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, collision, wsdl2java

I'm developing a web-service implementation base on a wsdl.
In a xsd linked to the wsdl there is a complex choice like this:

```
 <xs:sequence>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:element name="BinaryTerm" type="TermType" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                <xs:element name="BinaryExpression" type="ExpressionType"/>
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="Operator" type="SimpleOperatorType"/>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:element name="BinaryTerm" type="TermType"/>
                <xs:element name="BinaryExpression" type="ExpressionType"/>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>
```

Every time I generated the class implementation I obtain a class, ExpressionType, with a list
of JAXBElement due to the duplicate name BinaryTerm and BinaryExpression.
I've read a lot of thread suggesting to use bindings.xml with these options:

```
<jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false" fixedAttributeAsConstantProperty="true" choiceContentProperty="true">
```

But nothing changed in my ExpressionType class.
Anyone can suggest how to manage this XSD related to WSDL.
I can't change these definition files.
Thanks, Andrea

Answer (score 0):

when I want to generate classes with no JAXBElement use this binding. test it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc" jaxb:version="2.1">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false">
                <xjc:serializable />
            </jaxb:globalBindings>
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Like I stated before I've just try with this option but dont work, same behaviour as before.

Comment: you right Andrea. I tested it and I get JAXBElements. look at this comment. I think there is no way to run away from JAXBElement because of the choice element https://stackoverflow.com/a/31478362/9047449.